# "npm ERR! Invalid Version:" on resolutions in package.json in php:8.1-fpm image

Tags: node.js, npm, dockerfile, fpm, php-8.1

**NOTE:** It's not a question, it's sharing of todays headache, hopefully it will save somebody some time.

Our builds started to fail with the error

```
#29 [22/27] RUN npm install
#29 1.031 npm ERR! Invalid Version: ^4.2.4
#29 1.033 
#29 1.033 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#29 1.034 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-06-14T13_07_01_675Z-debug-0.log
#29 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1
```

Today's (Jun 14, 2023) update for the `php:8.1-fpm` included upgrade for *Debian* which installs *nodejs v18* and *npm v9.2*. However our node packages where prepared with *nodejs* v12 and *npm v7.5* the versions installed with previous *Debian*

After short investigate I found out that the error occurs on the following *package.json* entries

`"scripts": { "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions" }, "resolutions": { "graceful-fs": "^4.2.4" }`

After several unsuccessful tries to downgrade *nodejs* and *npm* I finally came up to a decision to install previous build of `php:8.1-fpm` by changing the `Dockerfile` from
`FROM php:8.1-fpm`
to
`FROM php:8.1-fpm@sha256:f884993fb0965ebdf6e3b7111f01738e5f1b0f143bcabba72de0f99aed07e668`

Adjusting of `package.json` and `package.lock` to *nodejs 18* andor *npm 9.2* to be done ASAP.

Comment: If you want to do a PSA, post it as a question and provide your own answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer